# Uploading third party artificate to nexus

Tags: nexus

**I have a pom.xml file and zip file of a artificate. Is there any other way to upload this in to nexus apart from nexus web interface **

Comment: @Anybody can give a sugesstion it is possible to do it automatically ..      By giving only some command or any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are quite few ways, see here: https://support.sonatype.com/entries/22189106-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-